NLP techniques to count job skills match
In our job portal search we are performing search by using dense embedding of Job Title + Skills across a pool of candidates. After this first step of retreival I'm planning to perform rerank based on number of skills matched. For example: 4 out of 7 skills matched
Since I'm using dense embedding I can't derive exactly how many skills matched and I can't simply do a keyword overlapping because that would fail for sceanrios like "ETL Tools" and "ETL", "Data Analysis" and "Data Visualisation" etc..
I'm planning to use SPLADE embedding to acheive this, is SPLADE a good way to solve this? or are there any other better ways of hanling this?
I can think of adding synonyms but that would be too difficult to maintain.
